# ASP.Net vnext beta 5 reference non vnext project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

After migrating to beta5 it seems that I can't reference usual "Class library" project anymore. It works great with beta4 though.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create ASP.Net 5 Web application (or "Class Library (package)")
2. Create "Class library" project (not package)
3. Add reference from Web Application to Class Library project

If run "dnu restore" from PowerShell, it runs without errors, however visual studio show reference error, and during build I got: Error     Dependency ClassLibrary1 >= 1.0.0-* could not be resolved   WebApplication1

[image]

Platform: Windows 8.1 x64, Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (RTM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that my library projects were built for .Net Framework 4.5.2, and in beta5 this is not working for some reason with dnx 4.5.1.
Downgrading libraries to Framework 4.5.1 fixes the issue.

Still it works with beta4.

Eventually I end up with dnx 46 and Framework 4.6 in beta6

Comment: I have the same issue, except that my projects are built for 4.5. Hope your solution will fix my issue as well!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and should be addressed in future releases soon. As you discovered, it comes from target framework version in the reference project being higher than version in the target project, which prevents it from being resolved.